# How to I set color in NSDatePicker Graphical Mode

Tags: swift, cocoa, nsdatepicker

I have a file list with creation time and I want to show it as different colour in NSDataPickerView. like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XiDt1.png) How can I achieve this?
I've tried `self.datePicker.textColor = NSColor.redColor()` but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
self.datePicker.setValue(NSColor.redColor(), forKey: "textColor")
```

I am not sure, it will work for `NSDatePicker` or not, but its working for `UIDatePicker`!

Answer (score 0):

The below works
self.datePicker.backgroundColor = NSColor.yellowColor()

[image]